# Помощь с подсчётом в датасете pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Имеется следующий датасет:

|  | date | user | event_type | parameter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2020-04-01_00:01:08 770906 | 770906 | 3 | unknown |
| 1 | 2020-04-01_00:00:30 527877 | 527877 | 1 | text |
| 2 | 2020-04-01_00:01:12 539948 | 539948 | 3 | picture |
| 3 | 2020-04-01_00:01:20 107541 | 107541 | 3 | picture |
| 4 | 2020-04-01_00:01:38 374954 | 374954 | 4 | text |

Надо найти день, когда число уникальных пользователей, отправивших текстовое сообщение (`event_type=4`, `parameter=text`), было максимальным.

Также нужно определить 20-минутный интервал [time; time + 20 min), в течение которого произошло больше всего событий?
Если таких интервалов несколько, нужно найти начало самого позднего.

Описание переменных:

```console
date        object
user        int64
event_type  int64
parameter   object
dtype: object
```

Comment: Помощь это СОВМЕСТНАЯ деятельность, а вы хотите посмотреть как отработает кто-то другой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создадим **DataFrame** по подобию:

```python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from random import randint as r

day = lambda : "%02d" % r(1,30)
hour = lambda : "%02d" % r(0,23)
min_sec = lambda : "%02d" % r(0,59)
user = lambda : "%06d" % r(100000,999999)

rows_c=100000
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['2020-04-{}_{}:{}:{}'.format(day(),hour(),min_sec(),min_sec()) for _ in range(0,rows_c)],
    'user': ["%06d" % r(100000,999999) for _ in range(0,rows_c)],
    'event_type': [r(1,4) for _ in range(0,rows_c)],
    'parameter': [['unknown', 'text', 'picture'][r(0,2)] for _ in range(0,rows_c)]
})
df.date = df.date + ' ' + df.user
df
```

###### Вывод:

```
        date                        user    event_type  parameter
0       2020-04-08_16:12:07 395528  395528  2           text
1       2020-04-10_21:10:21 682091  682091  2           unknown
2       2020-04-30_15:06:42 738315  738315  3           picture
3       2020-04-01_20:09:04 723756  723756  2           picture
4       2020-04-20_09:04:02 859750  859750  4           unknown
... ... ... ... ...
99995   2020-04-05_01:45:29 801973  801973  2           picture
99996   2020-04-07_05:48:39 379318  379318  2           text
99997   2020-04-11_04:24:33 581294  581294  2           picture
99998   2020-04-13_13:17:48 807151  807151  4           text
99999   2020-04-24_10:34:03 362205  362205  2           text

100000 rows × 4 columns
```

---

## Задача 1

> Надо найти день, когда число уникальных пользователей, отправивших текстовое сообщение (`event_type=4`, `parameter=text`), было максимальным.

В первую очередь приведём колонку `date` к формату `datetime`. Затем делаем фильтр по `event_type` и `parameter`. Убираем дубликаты из `user`, чтобы получить уникальных пользователей. Делаем `groupby` по дням и выводим день в котором было больше всего этих пользователей.

```python
df.date = df.date.str.replace(r'\s.*','', regex=True)
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date, format='%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S')

filtered_df = df[(df.event_type == 4) & (df.parameter == 'text')]
filtered_df = filtered_df.drop_duplicates(subset=['user'])
filtered_df.groupby(df.date.dt.day).size().idxmax()
```

###### Вывод:

```
10
```

---

## Задача 2

> Также нужно определить 20-минутный интервал [time; time + 20 min), в течение которого произошло больше всего событий? Если таких интервалов несколько, нужно найти начало самого позднего.

Интервал нужно определить на отфильтрованной таблице? Далее код работает с неотфильтрованной, т.к. из задачи не ясно.

```python
max_c = 0
for x in df.index:
    count = df.date[(df.date >= df.date.loc[x]) & (df.date < df.date.loc[x] + pd.Timedelta(20, "m"))].count()
    if count > max_c:
        ixs = [x]
        max_c = count
    elif count == max_c:
        ixs.append(x)
df.loc[ixs].date.idxmax()
```

###### Вывод:

```
76910
```

Получили index наиболее позднего события в интервале 20-и минут которого было наибольшее количество событий.

Сами события можно вывести через:

```python
ix = df.loc[ixs].date.idxmax()
df[(df.date >= df.date.loc[ix]) & (df.date < df.date.loc[ix] + pd.Timedelta(20, "m"))]
```

Делать итератор, конечно, не очень хорошо, можно было бы сделать через:

```python
df.index = df.date
gr = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='20min')])
```

Но в подходе с итератором я больше уверен.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь! 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, к 1-й задаче у вас вывод «10», не совсем понятно, что это значит - день или индекс? 
Дело в том, что нужен день в таком же виде, как строка date. 
Заранее спасибо

Comment: @Artem день, индекс нет смысла выводить, т.к. за день строчек много. В задаче указано "найти день", день найден. Спасибо в комментариях не принято говорить, пройдите [тур](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Понял! А если в первой задаче требуется узнать этот максимум (число уникальных пользователей, отправивших текстовое сообщение), то можно просто вызвать filtered_df.shape и соответственно первое число будет указывать этот максимум?

Comment: @Artem `df.loc[ixs].date.max()` покажет само число

Comment: нет-нет, я про другое. Если требуется узнать максимальное кол-во уникальных пользователей, отправивших текстовое сообщение, то подойдет filtered_df.shape ?

Comment: @Artem не подойдёт, это будет число по всем дням и пользователи неуникальные. Тур, я так понимаю, вы не прочитали.

Comment: тур прочитал подскажите, пожалуйста, как тогда мне узнать максимальное кол-во уникальных пользователей, отправивших текстовое сообщение?

Comment: @Artem уберите из `idxmax()` слово `ixd`, всё. `filtered_df.groupby(df.date.dt.day).size().idxmax()`

Comment: отметил ваш ответ галочкой ) спасибо еще раз! последний вопрос.
Назовем сессией - последовательный набор событий одного пользователя. Сессия заканчивается, если пользователь не совершал никаких действий в течение 30 или более минут. Нужно "склеить" события в сессии и подсчитать число сессий, которые начались 2020-04-18.
Я сделал на первоначальном датасете так: 
`df[df['date']=='2020-04-18']`
Это верно?

Comment: @Artem фильтрация по дню верная, да. Чтобы смотреть период в 30 минут, нужен `pd.Timedelta(30, "m")`, подсмотрите в втором ответе.

Comment: пытаюсь сделать так `df[df['date']=='2020-04-18' + pd.Timedelta(20, "m")]` - не получается :(

Comment: не подскажите, как правильно?

Comment: @Artem задайте отдельный вопрос. Ветка комментариев и так уже очень длинное, и то что Вы спрашиваете в изначальных не было.

Comment: создал новый вопрос